# Trying to adjust picture size based on device size

Tags: xaml, uwp

I'm trying to adjust picture sizes on different sized devices on the UWP platform. But facing some issues on the code below. I'm trying to use Visual State Manager so that image size would be adjusted if opened on different sized devices

```
<Setter Target="rowDefNavPanel" Value="0"></Setter>
<Setter Target="imglearn.(width)" Value="180"/>
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Xaml code

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="ms-appx:///Assets/Home/home_android.jpg"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>            
        <RowDefinition x:Name="rowDefNavPanel" Height="*"/>            
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>        
        <RelativePanel x:Name="homepanel">            
            <Image x:Name="imglearn" Source="Assets/Home/btn_learn_color.png"              
           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
           Margin="20,90,0,60"               
           Width="180" Height="200"  Stretch="Uniform"
           />
            <Image x:Name="imgPaint" Source="Assets/Home/btn_paint.png"              
          RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="imglearn"
           Margin="200,140,0,0"
           Width="180" Height="200"  Stretch="Uniform"
          />
            <Image x:Name="imgQuiz" Source="Assets/Home/btn_quiz.png"              
           RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True"
           RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
           Margin="0,50,30,0"
           Width="180" Height="200" Stretch="Uniform"
           />
            <Image x:Name="OtherApps" Source="Assets/Home/btn_other_app.png"              
           RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
           RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True"
           Margin="0,0,30,0"
           Width="180" Height="200"  Stretch="Uniform"
           />
        </RelativePanel>

    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="vsState">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="rowDefNavPanel" Value="0"></Setter>
                    <Setter Target="imglearn.(width)" Value="180"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>      
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [VisualState.Setters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visualstate.setters.aspx). Both your setters use invalid syntax. See also the Remarks section on the [Setter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.setter.aspx) page.

Comment: @Clemens I checked and found that this line has error <Setter Target="rowDefNavPanel" Value="0"></Setter>                                        but i didn't get why error is here in this line                                                          <Setter Target="imglearn.(width)" Value="180"/>       .If any solution is there  please provide that.

Comment: `<Setter Target="imglearn.(width)" Value="180"/> ` should be `<Setter Target="imglearn.Width" Value="180"/>`.